# Find html tags with specific attribute and enclose text in curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I have to find any html tags with the attribute i18n in VsCode and then enclose it's static text inside curly brackets. Like so:

```
<p i18n>something</p>
<p i18n>{something | odd}</p>
```

I've spent hours looking around for regex that would work and so far had no luck.

Comment: See the absolutely canonical answer about parsing HTML with regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17300

Comment: I'm afraid SO is not a freelancer/search engine site. I think you need to start with attempt to create your own RegExp instead of just looking for something that is ready. Also, consider to add the reason for why you want to do that. Probably, there is another way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work (not extensively tested, and I won't be surprised if I've made any mistakes):

Put this in the search field and enable regex search mode: `(<[^>]+ i18n( [^>]\+)?>)([^<]*)(</\w>)`. Put this in the replace field: `$1{$3}$4`.

If you want to ignore things that already have a pair of content curly braces, then use `(<[^>]+ i18n( [^>]\+)?>)([^{][^<]*[^}])(</\w>)` in the search field.

Comment: it doesn't seem to find anything

Comment: @kevinlenske did you enable regex search mode? If you did, please add more example input to your question post. It works for me on the input you gave.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. 
<p class="mb-1 text-400" style="font-size: 12px" i18n>Question Feed</p>

Answer (score 0):

If the `<p>` tags contain other tags you must capture all content till the first `</p>` text.

Don't select the `<p>` tags where the content starts with a `{` using `(?!\{)`

Regex find:

`(<p(?: [^>]+)? i18n(?: [^>]+)?>)(?!\{)(.*?)(</p>)`

Replace with:

`$1{$2}$3`

---

This does not work if you want to do it with `<div>` tags because they can contain `<div>` tags. Then you need a HTML parser like Emmet.

Regex find:

`(<div(?: [^>]+)? i18n(?: [^>]+)?>)(?!\{)`

- with cursor in find widget: `Alt_Enter` to select all occurrences
- place all cursors **after** the selections: `ArrowRight`
- select the content of `<div>` tag: execute command: **Emmet: Balance Outward**
- remove `<div>` content: `Ctrl+X`
- type what you want before the content: `foobar` or could be an Emmet expression and `Tab`
- paste in the content: `Ctrl+V`
- type what you want after the content, if using an Emmet expression skip this
- leave Multi Cursor: `Esc`

Comment: Is there some reason the `{` isnot escaped: `(?!\{)` in your first find?  It doesn't work in the Find widget or search across files without it.

Comment: @Mark Good catch, it was typed without testing